ResourceNotFound || The specified resource does not exist. - When sending the GET Request to "List Containers" Rest API in Postman

Following this MS Doc, but didn't get the expected result i.e., list of the containers in the storage accounts:
GET API: https://strprojuatuks001.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list
Error is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
    <Message>The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:alphanumericid
Time:2024-04-20T05:51:35.1180726Z</Message>
</Error>


Did you add Authorization request header in the request?

Yes, when I add the Authorization as Bearer Token and provided the value - I got the error like <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Authentication scheme Bearer is not supported in this version.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>

how to pass the sAS key/token as a header to the request?

if you are using bearer token, please add the following request header: x-ms-version: 2023-08-03.

You add your SAS Token to the URL and do not pass it as a header to your request. Your request URL would be something like https://strprojuatuks001.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&<your-sas-token>.

Few things:

Request to list containers in a storage account must be authorized. You would need to include Authorization header in your request. To learn about various authorization schemes available, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage.

Regarding the Authentication scheme Bearer is not supported in this version error, the reason you are getting this is because you have not included x-ms-version request header in your request. If this is not included in the request, then the REST API picks up the default service version which does not have support for bearer token authentication. To fix this error, you would need to include x-ms-version header and set its value to a version that supports bearer token authentication. For example, x-ms-version: 2023-08-03.

Regarding how to pass the sAS key/token as a header to the request, simple answer is that you do not include SAS Token as a header to the request. A SAS token is always added to your request URL. If you are using a SAS token, your request URL would be something like https://strprojuatuks001.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&<your-sas-token>. Also, since you are trying to list blob containers with a SAS token, please ensure that you have created an Account SAS Token.



I have added x-ms-version: 2023-08-03 and passed the new bearer token in the Authorization but I didn't get the expected result. Instead, got this error - https://i.imgur.com/CB3eL2g.png

The error indicates there is an issue with the way you acquired the token. I would recommend asking a separate question for that and provide all the details there (including those details in this question would change the intent of this question drastically).
